# How to get all OpenText Content Server categories in one call?

Tags: java, web-services, opentext

I'm currently on a project that involves OpenText Content Server 10.5 SP1 Update 2015-03.

I'm trying to find out if is possible to get all categories from the System Category Volume with one call using Java SOAP web services or REST.

On the web services side I found a couple of methods exposed by the DocumentManagement WSDL `GetCategoryDefinition` and `GetCategoryDefinitions` which require categoryIDs as argument.

On the REST side I managed to obtain access to categories but after a quite long trip:

1. call to `otcs/cs.exe?func=search.GetCategoryVolume` gives as a response an URL for the subsequent call
2. call to `otcs/cs.exe?func=ll&ObjID=2005&objAction=XMLExport&scope=1` gives the id of the system category volume along with category IDs
3. call to `otcs/cs.exe?func=ll&ObjID=21361&objAction=XMLExport&scope=1` gives the required info about the category.

I would like to have a single call returning all information about categories I need.

Is it possible to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible.

What you need to do:

1.) Find all IDs of the Categories, you want the definitions for

2.) call `DocumentManagementWS.getCategoryDefinitions(IDs)`

**example**

In my project we store all Categories in Folders, and not in the CategoryVolume of Content server.

```
// INFO: variable dm is an instance of the documentManagement-Webservice

// 1.) read the folder of the Categories
Node categoryRoot = dm.getNodeByPath(configRoot.getID(), Arrays.asList("Categories"));

// 2.) find all Ids of the categories
List<Node> categories = dm.listNodes(categoryRoot.getID(), false);

if (categories != null) {
    for (Node category : categories) {
        if (category.getType().equals("Category")) {
            categoryIds.add(category.getID());
        }
    }
}

// 3.) Read all defintitions of the categories
List<AttributeGroupDefinition> categoryDefinitions = dm.getCategoryDefinitions(categoryIds);
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. We store categories in folders too. Could you explain me how I can get the configRoot object?

Comment: our configRoot - this Node gets read before - is the node, which holds all configurations. It has a nickname, so we read it by its nickname before. just call dm.getNodeByNickname("theNickname")

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not exactly program oriented but you know about the handler "`cs.exe?func=attributes.dump`" ? This is the UI version of what you are asking.